# Increasing the Data Locality in Matrix Multiplication

Tags: c, optimization, matrix-multiplication

In matrix multiplication we do something like this

```
 for (i = 0; i < N; i = i + 1)
   for (j = 0; j < N; j = j + 1)
      A[i*N + j] = (double) random() / SOME_NUMBER;     

 for (i = 0; i < N; i = i + 1)
    for (j = 0; j < N; j = j + 1)
       B[i*N + j] = (double) random() / SOME_NUMBER;


 for (i = 0; i < N; i = i + 1)
    for (j = 0; j < N; j = j + 1)
       for (k = 0; k < N; k = k + 1)
            C[i*N + j] = C[i*N + j] + A[i*N + k]*B[k*N + j];
```

How can we increase the locality of data to optimize the multiplication loop

Comment: Google for "cache blocking" or "loop tiling".

Comment: Store B in transposed form: B[j*N + i] = ramdom() / SOME_NUMBER;

Comment: If that's not possible, rewrite the multiplication to loop on j first, then rewrite the first product of column j of B (with row 0 of A) to extract the elements of B[*;j] into a sequential N-vector, and use that sequential copy throughout the rest of the products for that column.

Comment: That's great @MikeHousky it really worked good. Seen significant performance improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store B in transposed form:

```
B[j*N + i] = ramdom() / SOME_NUMBER;
```

You'll also have to access the transposed array in that order:

```
C[i*N + j] = C[i*N + j] + A[i*N + k]*B[j*N + k];
```

If that's not possible, rewrite the multiplication to loop on j first, then rewrite the first product of column j of B (with row 0 of A) to extract the elements of B[*;j] into a sequential N-vector, and use that sequential copy throughout the rest of the products for that column.

The idea is to get the columns of B into consecutive memory words.  The transpose does that, very naturally, but it may not be practical to keep in that format.  (For example, if B is later multiplied on the right, then the original order works better.  The second suggestion keeps a copy of one column into an array of consecutive words, while computing an one sum of products to make full use of the memory reads on that copy.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Understood it with Cache Blocking and loop tiling.